# Can't send/receive cookies to backend reactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cookies, frontend, backend

I have been trying to register, login and then get some "Challenges (some data)" from my backend. I have managed to register and log in. However, when I request the challenges I get a message back saying "no cookie found". I have tried setting "withcredentials" to every value possible but I can not figure out why I am getting this error. I recreated my code using a simple "create-react-app":

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const create = async (id) => {
    const myPost = {
      
      username: "foo",
      password: "bar",
    }
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/users/createUser',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(myPost),
      credentials: "include"
    }
    )
    const data = await res.json()
    console.log(data)
  }
  const login = async (id) => {
    const myPost = {
      
      username: "foo",
      password: "bar",
    }
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/users/login',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(myPost),
      credentials: "include"
    }
    )
    const data = await res.json()
    console.log(data)  }
  const getChall = async (id) => {
    const myPost = {
      
      username: "foo",
      password: "bar",
    }
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/challenges/getAllActive',
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      credentials:'same-origin'
    }
    )
    const data = await res.json()
    console.log(data)
    
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
      <button onClick={create}>create </button>
      <button onClick={login}>login </button>
      <button onClick={getChall}>getChall </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Also some code from the backend:

````
const getAllActive = async (req,res) => {
    const allActive = [];
    for (var index in req.user.activeChallenges){
        allActive.push(await Challenge.findById(req.user.activeChallenges[index].challengeId));
    }
    res.json(allActive);
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

Where is the code in the backend that is returning the cookie?  Usually the response will be something like this:

```
        res.cookie("token", token, { maxAge:1000 * 60 * 60 })
        // above cookie expires after 60 minutes
        res.end()
```

or here's another rudimentary example:

```
exports.get = function(request, response, db) {
    let msg = { username: "", password: "" };
    let username;
    let password;
    if (request.body.name == 'joe'){
      msg.username = "correct";
    }else{
      msg.username = "incorrect";
    }
    if (request.body.password == 'sesame'){
      msg.password = "correct";
    }else{
      msg.password = "incorrect";
    }
    if (msg.username == 'correct' && msg.password == 'correct'){
        response.cookie('spongebob', 'squarepants').send(JSON.stringify(msg));
    } else {
        response.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
    }
}
```

Comment: For the above code in context see this working example on Glitch:  https://glitch.com/~hollow-tremendous-donkey  When you login look particularly at the code executed in public/client.js (which executes a fetch from the client to the server) and the code in controllers/login.js (which returns a cookie if the correct credentials have been sent over).